# Widget not displaying on Stack and there is no Ink effect on InkResponse

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on my first Flutter App and I have encountered two problems.
- The `Container` widget housing my `Image` widget does not get displayed on the `Stack` widget.

- There is no Ink effect when tapping the `InkResponse` container

I have tried rewriting the `Container` to display the image and by using `Image.Network` for the url instead of assets but to no avail.

```dart
  final appLogo = new Container(
    child: new Image(
      image: new AssetImage('assets/discord.png')
    ),
  );

  List<Widget> _getApps(List apps) {
    List<Widget> _appWidgets = <Widget>[];
    // make a Grid tile of the Apps
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
      _appWidgets.add(
        new InkResponse(
        child: Center(
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              appLogo,
              new Container(height: 102, width: 102, color: Colors.red),
            ],
          )
        )
      ),
      );
    }
    return _appWidgets;
  }
```

`appLogo` should be displayed on the red box (`Container`) from my expectation and there should be a Splash when I tap on the `InkResponse` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your image needs to be added to your `pubspec.yaml` file like so:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Once you have that, you can access all your images inside "/images" or any folder name inside your project you want. Now you can access your image in this way:

```
Image.asset("images/myimage.jpg") // again, this in an example
```

Bear in mind that images are not affected by the ripple material effect, only the background of it (if the image is inside a bigger container with "empty" space). Second, you need an `InkWell` with `onTap:` method in order to show the ripple, to finish everything, you need a `Material` widget as this one provides the necessary effects.

So, if you want to see a the ripple effect behind the image and having it inside a Stack, you'll need to do something like:

```
Material(
   child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
             InkWell(
                 onTap: () {}, // The ripple only shows up if you have a onTap method.
                 child: Container(
                       height: 300, // 300 is a random value but has bigger height than the image itself.
                       child: Image.asset("images/myimage.jpg"),
                        ),
                 ),
             ],
    ),
)
```